# Class and interface design. Method not determined

Tags: java

I've created a super class (abstract) as it and its child classes inherit data from an interface (named Profitable). During compilation, an error is returned where it does not recognize method calcuateRevenue(). The method is declared in the interface, and then it is defined in the child classes (each class uses different means to calculate revenue). Since there are several classes, I will include the super class, one example of the child class, interface, and of course the main method (BradleyLangrehrP5). Am I missing something elementary, or is something designed terribly poorly?

```
public class BradleyLangrehrP5
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Create movieArray list
        Movie[] movieArrayList = new Movie[6];

        //Instantiate movies from each subclass
        movieArrayList[0] = new Animated(.1, 5.0 , "Finding Nemo", 
                "Andrew Stanton", 2003, 90.0);
        movieArrayList[1] = new Animated(.08, 3.0, "Shrek", 
                "Andrew Adamson", 2001, 60.0);
        movieArrayList[2] = new Documentary(4.0, 2.5, 
                "Fidel: The Untold Story", "Estela Bravo", 2001, 72.0);
        movieArrayList[3] = new Documentary(6.0, 3.25, 
                "An Inconvenient Truth", "David Guggenheim", 2006, 1.0);
        movieArrayList[4] = new Drama(25, 4.5, "Red Lights", 
                "Rodrigo Cortes", 2012, 17.0);
        movieArrayList[5] = new Drama(15, 3.75, "The Godfather", 
                "Francis Ford Coppola", 1972, 6.5);
        displayNumberOfMoviesAndRevenue(movieArrayList);
    }

    public static void displayMovieArrayList(Movie[] movieArrayList)

    {

        for(int i = 0; i < movieArrayList.length; i++)

        {

            System.out.println(movieArrayList[i].toString());

        }

    }


    public static void displayNumberOfMoviesAndRevenue(Movie[] movieArrayList)
    {
        for (int i = 0;i < movieArrayList.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(movieArrayList[i].totalMovies());
            System.out.println(movieArrayList[i].calculateRevenue());
        }
    }
}

public class Movie
{
    private String title;
    private String director;
    private int year;
    private double productionCost;
    private static int totalMovies = 0;

    //Construct a default movie
    public Movie()
    {
        totalMovies++;
    }

    //Cosntruct movie with specific information
    public Movie(String title, String director, int year, double productionCost)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.director = director;
        this.year = year;
        this.productionCost = productionCost;
        totalMovies++;
    }

    //Accessors
    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDirector()
    {
        return director;
    }

    public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }

    public double getProductionCost()
    {
        return productionCost;
    }

    public int totalMovies()
    {
        return totalMovies;
    }

    //Mutators
    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setDirector(String director)
    {
        this.director = director;
    }

    public void setYear(int year)
    {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public void setProductionCost(double productionCost)
    {
        this.productionCost = productionCost;
    }

    //Effectors
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Movie: " + getTitle() + "was directed by " + getDirector() + 
                "with a production cost of " + getProductionCost();
    }
}

public final class Animated extends Movie implements Profitable
{
    private double royaltyRate;
    private double incomeRelatedProducts;

    //No arg constructor
    public Animated()
    {
        super();
    }

    //Constructor with arguments
    public Animated(double royaltyRate, double incomeRelatedProducts, String title,
            String director, int year, double productionCost)
    {
        super(title, director, year, productionCost);
        this.royaltyRate = royaltyRate;
        this.incomeRelatedProducts = incomeRelatedProducts;
    }

    //Accessors
    public double getRoyaltyRate()
    {
        return royaltyRate;
    }

    public double getIncomeRelatedProducts()
    {
        return incomeRelatedProducts;
    }

    //Mutators
    public void setRoyaltyRate(double royaltyRate)
    {
        this.royaltyRate = royaltyRate;
    }

    public void setIncomeRelatedProducts(double incomeRelatedProducts)
    {
        this.incomeRelatedProducts = incomeRelatedProducts;
    }

    //Effectors
    public double calculateRevenue()
    {
        return incomeRelatedProducts * royaltyRate;
    }

    public double calculateProfit()
    {
        double profit = calculateRevenue() - getProductionCost();
        return profit;
    }

    public String getCategory()
    {
        return "Animated";
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "This is an animated movie, and it is";
    }
}

public interface Profitable
{
    double calculateRevenue();
    double calculateProfit();
    String getCategory();
}//end of Profitable interface
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 System.out.println(movieArrayList[i].calculateRevenue());
```

You are trying to call `calculateRevenue` on a `Movie`. But it is defined in the interface `Profitable`, which has no relationship to `Movie`. The actual subclasses of `Movie` may very well implement `Profitable`, but the compiler does not know about that.

You need to either declare `Movie implements Profitable` or do a typecast to `Profitable` before calling the method.

Comment: Wow, such a simple answer. Thanks for the feedback. I can't believe I missed that previously.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to let your super class `Movie` to implement `Profitable` as you may want to give any default implementation to the method `calculateRevenue`. Here you are implementing the interface `Profitable` in you child class which means that you are giving the flexibility of `Profitable` i.e it may be added or it may not be depends on the child class implementations. If that is your  intention keep it as it is and when you are calling `calculateRevenue` do a proper type checks on `Profitable` using `instanceof` operator  and call the methods. But if you want your `Movie` class should have this functionality by all means let your `Movie` class implement the interface `Profitable`.  So only Without doing that your code will throw compilation error saying `calculateRevenue` is not found in class `Movie`  and that is what you are getting.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 0;i < movieArrayList.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(movieArrayList[i].totalMovies());
                System.out.println(movieArrayList[i].calculateRevenue());
            }
```

This is referencing to class `Movie`. Try adding a cast.

```
for (int i = 0;i < movieArrayList.length; i++)
        {
            if(movieArrayList[i] instanceof Animated){
               System.out.println((Animated)movieArrayList[i].totalMovies());
               System.out.println((Animated)movieArrayList[i].calculateRevenue());
             }
             //...do other IFs

        }
```